# dart alternate for a lot of if elseiif

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart

I want to replace an URL String in Dart with another String.
Example:

```dart
if (url == "http://www.example.com/1") {
home = "example";
} else if (url == "http://www.example.com/2") {
home = "another example";
}
```

Isn't there a better way with less code and maybe faster? I'd have to do this over 60 times..

Comment: A "better way" is highly opinion based. Better in what ? Readbility ? Maintainability ? Speed ?

Comment: If there is a better way especially in less code

Comment: Well, your second case could be removed entirely since its condition will never be true...

Comment: It's just a typo.. Of course there would be another number at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want less code, you can do somtehing like this :

```
homes = {
  "http://www.example.com/1": "example",
  "http://www.example.com/2": "another example",
  "http://www.example.com/3": "yet another one",
};
home = homes[url];
```

Answer (score 5):

I like Muldec's answer as I personally find switch statements to be a bit awkward to read.  I also like the option of having a default so you could 'kind of' redefine the switch statement.  The additional benefit is that you can use it inline as an expression and it is still typesafe...like this.

```
case2(myInputValue,
  {
    "http://www.example.com/1": "example",
    "http://www.example.com/2": "another example",
    "http://www.example.com/3": "yet another one",
  }, "www.google");
```

The case2 code could be

```
TValue case2<TOptionType, TValue>(
  TOptionType selectedOption,
  Map<TOptionType, TValue> branches, [
  TValue defaultValue = null,
]) {
  if (!branches.containsKey(selectedOption)) {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  return branches[selectedOption];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch statement.

```
switch(variable_expression) { 
   case constant_expr1: { 
      // statements; 
   } 
   break; 

   case constant_expr2: { 
      //statements; 
   } 
   break; 

   default: { 
      //statements;  
   }
   break; 
}
```

References

- [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_switch_case_statement)
- [Flutter Dart](https://flutterrdart.com/dart-switch-case-statement-with-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

**Mapp**

```
              var mapper = {
                  'discountCode1': 0.5,
                  'discountCode2': 0.7,
                  'discountCode3': 0.8,
                };
```

**Function**

```
             double getDiscount(double price, String discountCode) {
                  if (mapper.containsKey(discountCode)) {
                    return mapper[discountCode]! * price;
                  } else {
                    return price;
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just store the value "http://www.example.com" in a string variable and concatinate everytime. Refer below code

```
String originalUrl = 'https://www.example.com';
if (url == originalUrl + '/1') {

}
```

Comment: Or else you can use Switch Case